# Confirmation link not working (Devise in Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For e.g. when clicking the link within email, I got redirected in browser to http://0.0.11.184/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=rcqn2fYMdAYYwZ-d_fXh

with error message:

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I have my entire repo up at https://github.com/cheese1884/197451.git as I'm not sure which codes I am to post up online here for possible faults. Just need this to work in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in Mailcatcher. Thanks guys!